# Select option using Jquery base on text

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select>
  <option value="something else">James</option>
  <option value="something else">John</option>
</select>
```

For some reason I can do `$('select').val('something else')` because the value attribute is used for other stuff. To avoid messing up the current working stuff, how do I select the element based on the text value? Says I already got the value `James` and `John`.

Comment: The values on each option need to be unique when submitting the form or getting the select value.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("select option").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == 'John';
}).prop('selected', true)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="something else">James</option>
  <option value="something else">John</option>
</select>
```

use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below

```
 $("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text();
```

This will provide you text

Answer (score 1):

`$('select').find('option[value="something else"]').prop("selected", true)`

Answer (score 1):

try with `$("select :selected").text();`

Answer (score 1):

Use `contains` for selecting the option by text like this.

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6uvzh86t/)

**Stack Example:**

```js
$(function() {
  var text = "John";
  $("select option:contains(" + text + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="something else">James</option>
  <option value="something else">John</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var selectText = function(elem, text) {
  if (elem && text) {
    elem.find('option').each(function() {
      var that = $(this);
      if (that.text() == text) {
        that.attr('selected', 'selected');
      }
    });
  }
}
selectText($('#target'), 'John');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="target">
<option value="something else">James</option>
<option value="something else">John</option>
</select>
```